# What is the differnce between "const X a" and "X const a" if X is the class

Tags: c++, variables, constants

i have a class name X, what is the difference between "const X a" and "X const a"

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Nothing.

A `const` qualifier applies to whatever is immediately to its left.  If there is nothing to its left then it applies to whatever is immediately to its right.

Comment: But there is a difference between `const int *a`, `int *const a` and `const int *const a`.

Comment: It is better however to write A const x to be in better harmony with the 'Right Left' rule

Comment: @Chubsdad: Personally I prefer the `A const x` form. But it is hard to argue that one is better than the other (its one of those style things). Now if you have a fantastic reason I would love to hear it (so I can also use it).

Comment: @Martin York: Me too!. One thing is that it is in harmony with 'Right Left rule'. The other best reason I have so far encountered is from Chapter 1.4 of 'C++ Templates' by David Vandevoorde. It is definitely worth a read about its superiority in context of templates/typedef declarations

Comment: While I certainly understand why some people prefer `T const` over `const T` and I see the potential benefit of the style, I have always found it awkward and haven't gotten used to writing it that way.  It's just weird.

Answer (score 6):

In this case, there's no difference at all.

When you have a pointer or a reference, a change that might *look* almost the same *is* significant though. Given something like:

```
T * a;
```

The position of `const` (or `volatile`) relative to the asterisk *is* significant:

```
T const * a;
T * const a;
```

The first one says that `a` is a pointer to a `const T` (i.e., you can't modify the T object that `a` refers to). The second one says that `a` is a const point to a (non-const) T -- i.e., you can modify what `a` points *at*, but you can't modify the pointer itself, so you can't point it at a different object. Of course, you can also do both:

```
T const * const a;
```

This means you can't change the pointer itself *or* the `T` object it refers to.

Answer (score 2):

If you use simple types (embedded or custom) then that is a matter of taste.

In case of using pointers there is a simple general rule: if const is placed before '*' then the data pointed is constant and otherwise the pointer itself is constant, you can't change its value.

For example:

```
const int  a=1;  // 'a' value can't be changed
const int* q;    // the data that 'a' point to is constant
int const* q;    // the same
int* const p=&a; // the pointer is constant: const is behind '*'
```

so

```
int b=2;
p = &b; // error: trying to change constant pointer
```